# Groovy: on the fly properties

Tags: grails, groovy

In Javascript you can define an object with properties a and b like so:

```
myObj={a:'a',b:'b'}
```

and then you can add a property c like so

```
myObj.c = 'c'
```

whats the equivalent of that in Groovy? Do I have to use metaClass?

Use case: JSON converters in Grails do not add transient properties to the response, i would like to just attach a random property to each element of my object list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `Map`, which has similar syntax and behavior:

```
def myObj [a:'a', b:'b']
myObj.c = 'c'
```

You can also attach behavior with Closures, e.g.

```
myObj.sayHello = { -> println 'Hi' }
```

and then call it like a method:

```
myObj.sayHello()
```

Comment: What if we are talking about a Domain class, I can't use a Map for that. I would like to add a property to each member of the List.

Comment: adding property to each member of the list is nothing but a map(key-value pair)

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from [Using methodMissing and propertyMissing](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+methodMissing+and+propertyMissing):

Groovy also supports propertyMissing for dealing with property resolution attempts. For a getter you use a propertyMissing definition that takes a String argument:

```
  class Foo {
       def propertyMissing(String name) { name }
    }
    def f = new Foo()

    assertEquals "boo", f.boo
```

For a setters you add a second propertyMissing definition that takes a value argument:

```
class Foo {
   def storage = [:]
   def propertyMissing(String name, value) { storage[name] = value }
   def propertyMissing(String name) { storage[name] }
}
def f = new Foo()
f.foo = "bar"

assertEquals "bar", f.foo
```

As with methodMissing you will likely want to dynamically register new properties at runtime to improve the performance of you code.

Comment: Steve, thank you for posting. I have 2 issue with this. 1. since Foo already has a map property storage you can just set f.storage.foo='bar'. 2 I don't think I want to decorate all of my grails domain classes with propertyMissing methods. It feels to heavy handed. I am still looking for more elegant solution.

Comment: Nice. Love that groovy X-Missing.

Comment: @DmitryB: 1) Yes, you could access f.storage.foo in that example. However, you can also access f.foo, which is what I thought you wanted to do. 2) You could play with using a Category to apply the propertyMissing methods to each of your domains.

Comment: Also, I think I understand your question better now. If you want to provide a custom JSON response for a grails domain object when using the converters (domainObj as JSON), you can use the InstanceMethodBasedMarshaller to register custom toJSON() methods in your domains. See http://lucy-michael.klenk.ch/index.php/informatik/grails/c/ for an XML based example.