# Groovy extended hashmap with a field

Tags: groovy, hashmap, extend

This doesn't work.  Shouldn't it?

```
class WeirdBean extends HashMap {
  public String inner = "set within"
  def getInner() { return this.inner }
  def getOuter() { return this.outer }
}

def o = WeirdBean.newInstance()
o.outer = "set without"
println o.getOuter()  // set without
println o.outer       // set without
assert o.outer == o.getOuter() // Pass

println o.getInner()  // set within
println o.inner       // null, even though public
assert o.inner == o.getInner() // Fail, o.inner is null
```

Comment: To access field directly you have to use `o.@inner` otherwise `o.inner` will be treated as getting the value for the key `inner` which is apparently `null` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `Map::get` has higher precedence than `object.field` or `object.property`. Since a field access inside a class doesn't go through the getter, this works:

```
class WeirdBean extends HashMap {
  public String inner = "set within"
  def getInner() { return this.inner }

  def getProperty(String property) { 
    (property == 'inner') ? inner : super.get(property) 
  }

  def getOuter() { return this.outer }
}

def o = WeirdBean.newInstance()
o.outer = "set without"
println o.getOuter()  // set without
println o.outer       // set without
assert o.outer == o.getOuter() // Pass

println o.getInner()  // set within
println o.inner       // null, even though public
assert o.inner == o.getInner() // Fail, o.inner is null
```

Comment: setProperty() looks like it still gets called when you set that property within the class (e.g. this.inner = "newthing") which is different from a groovy bean, and exactly the weirdness/functionality I was looking for

Comment: Wow. There is also `propertyMissing`, if you want only if the property doesn't exists.

Comment: Yes, `propertyMissing` has to have a storage mechanism (mainly a map) inside the class which will refuge the fields and provide accessor methods for the fields. @WillP

Comment: @dmahapatro right - I was looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740702/groovy-on-the-fly-properties
I also wondered about the performance of that, but I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Expression `o.inner` returns key from HashMap. There's no such key `inner` so null is returned, while inside `getInner()` method value of `this.inner` field is returned (which is set to `"set without"`. That's why.